# Multiple and count rows in SQL

Tags: sql, hadoop

I have table with warehouse intakes and outtakes. I want to multiple rows to every day and then count and sum storage cost to every day. ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8GCl.png))

```
+ -------- + -------------- + ---------- + ---------- + -------------- + ------------ +
| material | wasting_time_a | indate     | outdate    | count_material | storage_cost |
+ -------- + -------------- + ---------- + ---------- + -------------- + ------------ +
| 963651   | 5              | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-06 | 2              | 0.04357      |
| 963651   | 6              | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-07 | 1              | 0.02615      |
| 963651   | 7              | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-08 | 1              | 0.0305       |
| 963651   | 11             | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-12 | 4              | 0.1917       |
| 963651   | 12             | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-13 | 1              | 0.05229      |
| 963651   | 13             | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-14 | 3              | 0.1699       |
| 963651   | 14             | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-15 | 9              | 0.5490       |
| 963651   | 15             | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-16 | 7              | 0.4575       |
| 963651   | 16             | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-17 | 2              | 0.1394       |
| 963651   | 18             | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-19 | 5              | 0.3922       |
| 963651   | 19             | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-20 | 6              | 0.4968       |
| 963651   | 20             | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-21 | 6              | 0.5229       |
| 963651   | 21             | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-22 | 2              | 0.1830       |
| 963651   | 22             | 2016-12-02 | 2016-12-23 | 1              | 0.0959       |
| 963651   | 2              | 2016-12-22 | 2016-12-23 | 2              | 0.01743      |
| 963651   | 9              | 2016-12-22 | 2016-12-30 | 3              | 0.1177       |
| 963651   | 10             | 2016-12-22 | 2016-12-31 | 1              | 0.04357      |
| 963651   | 12             | 2016-12-22 | 2017-01-02 | 1              | 0.05229      |
| 963651   | 14             | 2016-12-22 | 2017-01-04 | 2              | 0.1220       |
+ -------- + -------------- + ---------- + ---------- + -------------- + ------------ +
```

Waiting_time_a is just diff between indate and outdate. Count_material is count of material outtaken from warehouse on outdate.

Storage costs increase every day, so I need to count each day specifically. My idea is to count each day this way: I multiple rows from indate to outdate for each row and in the end I will sum it. Based on my table storage costs for 2016-12-02 will be SUM of count_material group by indate. But I don't know how to count it for 2016-12-03.

I am using Impala, but every SQL will help :)

Table will like:

```
+ ---------- + ------------------ +
| DATE       | total_storage_cost |
+ ---------- + ------------------ +
| 2016-12-02 | 40                 |
| 2016-12-03 | 47                 |
| 2016-02-04 | ...                |
| 2016-02-05 | ...                |
| 2016-02-06 | ...                |
+ ---------- + ------------------ +
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What do you multiply exactly? If I understood correctly, you are just summing up count_material grouped by indate?

Comment: Could you specify a bit more how the total_storage_cost should be calculated, it's not that clear. Whatever I do, I can't calculate the value of 40 for date 2016-12-02 like in your result

Comment: I am Sorry. 40 was just example. All I want to do is just devide storage cost by difference between indate and outdate and sum of material for that day. Then I want to add fake rows with counted storage cost for that day. 
Hope explain that correctly :)

Comment: `select (c.storage_cost) / (c.differencedays * c.sumcountmaterial) as total_storage_cost,
c.indate
from
(
select datediff(day, indate, outdate) as differenceofdays, indate, storage_cost,
b.countmaterial as sumcountmaterial
from warehouse a
inner join
(select sum(count_material) countmaterial, indate from warehouse
group by indate) b
on a.indate = b.indate 

)
c`. I think your query structure would be something like this

Comment: I didn't helped :( I need to count it to every day, even if I don't have specific date in table. So I need to have row for every day from 2016-12-02 till now()

Answer (score 1):

This could be a start. But how do you want to calculate it for the days that are not in the table? Maybe you could specify a bit further?

```
DECLARE @D TABLE(mDate DATE)
INSERT INTO @D VALUES ('20161201'),('20161202'),('20161203'),('20161204'),('20161205'),('20161206'),('20161207'),('20161208'),
                  ('20161209'),('20161210'),('20161211'),('20161212'),('20161213'),('20161214'),('20161215'),('20161216'),
                  ('20161217'),('20161218'),('20161219'),('20161220'),('20161221'),('20161222'),('20161223'),('20161224')
DECLARE @T TABLE(Material INT
            ,Waiting_Time_a INT
            ,Indate DATE
            ,Outdate DATE
            ,Count_Material INT
            ,Storage_cost DECIMAL(18,10))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(963651,5,'20161202','20161206',2,0.0435749999),
(963651,6,'20161202','20161207',1,0.026145),
(963651,7,'20161202','20161208',1,0.0305025000),
(963651,11,'20161202','20161212',4,0.19173),
(963651,12,'20161202','20161213',1,0.05229),
(963651,13,'20161202','20161214',3,0.1699425),
(963651,14,'20161202','20161215',9,0.5490449999),
(963651,15,'20161202','20161216',7,0.4575375),
(963651,16,'20161202','20161217',2,0.13944),
(963651,18,'20161202','20161219',5,0.3921750000),
(963651,19,'20161202','20161220',6,0.4967549999),
(963651,20,'20161202','20161221',6,0.522899999),
(963651,21,'20161202','20161222',2,0.183015),
(963651,22,'20161202','20161223',1,0.095865),
(963651,2,'20161222','20161223',2,0.01743),
(963651,9,'20161222','20161230',3,0.1176525000),
(963651,10,'20161222','20161231',1,0.04357499999),
(963651,12,'20161222','20170102',1,0.05229),
(963651,14,'20161222','20170104',2,0.1220100000)

SELECT d.mDate, t.dCost
FROM @D AS d
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT Indate, SUM(Storage_cost / Waiting_Time_a) AS dCost
     FROM @T
     GROUP BY Indate) AS t
        ON t.Indate = d.mDate
```

Answer (score 0):

For some RDBMS this could be done using [recursive CTE](https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/), but Impala does not support them.
For your case I'd suggest to create some table containing the single column only, containing the date with daily increment (2016-12-02, 2016-12-03, 2016-12-04, ...).
If you don't want any coding, this can be done via MS Excel, then export to csv, then import to hdfs.
Then you could use this table as in the table joins and date range filtering.

Answer (score 0):

@ All.  I have been following these Hadoop discussions for a couple weeks now.  I have read over 1,000 posts here at SO.  I'm also reading a couple of books on Hadoop.  This specific post makes me think Hadoop is just like SQL Server.  I don't really see a whole lot of difference between SQL Server and Hadoop.  Although, as I alluded to above, I am very new to the whole Hadoop concept.  I have been using SQL Server for almost 10 years now.  Is there a huge advantage for someone like me to learn Hadoop, if I already know SQL Server very well?  I'm just curious about this.

Thanks.